# Android do something when an app is launched

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I'm wondering if there is a way to detect if a certain app is running.

On SO, there are some related questions, but they are old.  So, I was wandering if from android >= 5.0 I can detect when a certain app is running.

I don't want to make it so that an app receives this info because it's probably impossible; I want to build a way to receive this information by my launcher.

Example: My launcher should show an overlaying popup when Whatsapp is launched on the phone.

Can I achieve this?  If so, how?

Comment: What hasn't worked with the other questions you've found?

Comment: They said it was not possible, but they were questions of more than 1-2 years ago.. I just wanted a newer info

Comment: I don't think it is possible to detect a third-party app. You could hook into the Activity lifecycle of your own apps.